# Metrizable space

Tags: general-topology

Somebody please explain me what is meant by a space **X is metrizable**?

What is the relationship between  metrizable and compactness, connectednes, regularity, normality and Hausdorffness?

Comment: Had you read the article of wikipedia on metrizability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metrizable is a topological space homeomorphic to a metric space. That is $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is metrizable when there exists a metric $d:X^2\to [0,+\infty)$ so that the topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ induced by $d$ coincides with $\mathcal{T}$. The spaces $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(X,\mathcal{T}_d)$ are homeomorphic. As any metric space is Hausdorff, every metrizable space is also Hausdorff.

Proving that a topological space is metrizable lets us in effect consider that space a metric space. Then we can define completeness of the space etc. For more information go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem) (as Seirios suggested). Now the relationship between metrizable and compactness etc. is the same as the relationship between metric spaces and compactness etc.

Comment: Typo error @ *homeorphic*.

Comment: @HaskellCurry Fixed. Thank you ( I always make typos when typing words like that)